# How can I convert a string to an array, matching multiple delimiters using Preg_match in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the following possible strings:

```
NL DE 
NL,DE
nl DE
nl de
NL/DE
NL,mismatch,DE
```

I'm looking for the `preg_match` that produces the following output given the inputs above.

```
array(
  [0]=>"NL",
  [1]=>"DE"
);
```

I've tried the following code:

```
preg_match_all('/(\w{2,2})/ui', $info["country"], $m);
```

but that seems to also cut up the word `mismatch`, which is undesired.

The regex should only match two letter country codes, everything else should be ignored.

How can I do this using `preg_match` in PHP?

Comment: you can easily explode this string ..why regex ?

Comment: @Baba, cause basically you can't explode this string easily unless I'm terribly mistaking...

Comment: @patrick You would need [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) around that to ensure that the match isn't longer than two chars. `/\b\w{2}\b/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// @claudrian Variant
function SplitCountries($string){
    // Sanity check
    if(!is_string($string)) return false;
    // Split string by non-letters (case insensitive)
    $slices = preg_split('~[^a-z]+~i', trim($string));
    // Keep only 2-letter words
    $slices = preg_grep('~^[a-z]{2}$~i', $slices);
    // Keep uniques
    $slices = array_unique($slices);
    // Done
    return $slices;
}

// @Wiseguy Variant
function SplitCountries($string){
    // Sanity check
    if(!is_string($string)) return false;
    // Capture only two letter packs
    if(!preg_match_all('~\\b[a-z]{2}\\b~i', trim($string), $slices)){
        return false;
    }
    // Keep uniques
    $slices = array_unique($slices[0]);
    // Done
    return $slices;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this solution even found "NL,mistmatch,[DE]", very concrete solution, thanks!

Comment: What about simply `preg_match_all('~\b[a-z]{2}\b~i', ...)`? Two birds with one stone, as the saying goes. [Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) would enforce a length of no more than two.

Comment: @Wiseguy (I initially wrote this for uppercased matches only. Then edited that out.) #1. In your code you are not capturing anything. #2. preg_match_all has a more complicated array output and he is obviously a beginner (no offense @patrick). So decided to break it down so he can learn from it too.

Comment: Then wouldn't this be a good teaching experience? Wouldn't hurt to use it then also add the longer version for more explanation. (BTW, shortly after you posted your answer, he did add a comment above that showed he was using `preg_match_all()`.) Also, I'm not sure what you mean about not capturing anything ([example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zMXFXz)).

Comment: @Wiseguy preg_match_all('~\b[a-z]{2}\b~i', ...) <- no capture ... do this : preg_match_all('~\b([a-z]{2})\b~i', ..., $matches) ... now you capture and can use $matches[1] to list the strings. Otherwise it would contain borders too in $matches[0] unless you do lookbehinds and lookaheads.

Comment: Word boundaries aren't characters; they're anchors just like `^` and `$`.

Comment: @Wiseguy ... he has multiple matches in a string (preg_match_all matches all as in many). So the \b is once ^, once $ and then it's space, coma, bracket... o.O Just try your code against his string.

Comment: Did _you_ try it? It correctly matches all of those strings. ([example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sRNkyk)) It works the same as `/(?<!\w)[a-z]{2}(?!\w)/`. I do not understand what you think the problem is.

Comment: @Wiseguy is awesome! And I upvoted your comment. \b is a non-capture :) I usually avoid special groups like this. I assumed it captures it... and those who assume as S-es. I'll update the code a bit.

Comment: Claudrian, no offence taken, don't worry. I'm not new to programming (by far), but relatively new to regex. I never got the hang of that! Your suggestion is in place and running great! I'll update it to @Wiseguy's suggestion. Actually I was looking for a solution like that. I came close, but never quite all the way there. Thanks Wiseguy!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you explode the string:

```
$string = 'NL DE 
NL,DE
nl DE
nl de
NL/DE
NL,mismatch,DE';
```

Using `explode` and `filter`:

```
$string = explode("\n",str_replace(array(",","/"," ","\r"), "\n", strtoupper($string)));
$string = array_unique(array_filter($string,function($v){$v = trim($v); return strlen($v) === 2;}));
var_dump($string);
```

If you want to play around with the string, try this:

```
$s = ",\n\t \r";
$t = strtok(strtoupper($string), $s);
$l = array();
while ( $t !== false ) {
    in_array($t, $l) OR strlen($t) == 2 AND $l[] = $t AND $t = strtok($s);
}
var_dump($l);
```

Output:

```
array
  0 => string 'NL' (length=2)
  1 => string 'DE' (length=2)
```

Comment: I stand corrected, but this seems mighty complicated. It sounded like something perfect for a regex...

Comment: that would need a regex to compare against though ;-)... I big advantage of this solution is that it also filters out doubles! So the array_unique had to be in there even with a regex solution. Same for the strtoupper. The only 'problem' I have is that your solution uses ',', '/',' ' and '\r' as delimiter. A regexp that looks for 2-letter words could use all delimiters, making it even more failsafe.

Comment: Update with another solution .. with out regex

Comment: Wiseguy came up with the final solution, one line of code, and relatively readable:

preg_match_all('~\b[a-z]{2}\b~i',$string,$l); var_dump($l);

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$result = array();
preg_match_all('/([a-z]{2})(?:.*)?([a-z]{2})/i',$text, $matches);
$result = array( strtolower( $matches[1][0] ), strtolower( $matches[2][0] ) );
```

You'll have the results in the $result array

Comment: yeah, but the input is user input, I don't know the word 'mismatch' is coming up. Sorry for not being specific enough about that

Comment: if you know it can be a word, you can replace with \w, if it can be anything, then it may be a bit more complex, can you clarify that part please?

Comment: First thing I tried was to look for a two-letter word 'cause basically that's what I need. If there are other words in there they can be ignored.